# Как заменить вариативное значение в строке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую. Есть значение `number`, которое может быть любым от нуля до млн. Необходимо на место в span с классом `quantity` иметь возможность менять изменять цифру 1 (может быть тоже любой от 0 до млн), на значение из `number`, но не нарушая целостности строки.

```js
< script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" > < /script>
var number = 3;
console.log($(".quantity").html());
```

```html
<span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">57.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
```

т.е. на выходе получить в данном случае:
`<span class="quantity">3 × <span class="amount">57.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так.

```
$(function(){
var number = 3;
var html=$(".quantity").html();
html=html.replace(/\d+/,number);
$(".quantity").html(html);
});
```

осталось еще только в классе total `<span class="total">57.000&nbsp;руб.</span>` подменить итоговое значение, полученное умножением на number

Comment: зачем же? это ТРИ раза по 57.000 руб. Видимо общий подсчет где-то в другом месте дальше происходит

Comment: @xaja вам кажется класс `total` плохим названием для итогового значения?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что значит

> не нарушая целостности строки

Но, например, вот так:

```
$(".quantity").text(number);
// $(".quantity").html(number); - почти тоже самое
```

Comment: это значит структура строки остается, а заменяется только числовое значение. да нет, же - при таком варианте мы получим только 3, а нужно `3 × <span class="amount">57.000&nbsp;руб.</span>`

Comment: @Вася, не парьтесь и оберните число в `span`, с ним и работайте

Comment: так ведь для того, чтобы обернуть - его нужно для начала найти..

Comment: @Вася, то есть у вас нет доступа непосредственно до html кода?

Comment: скажем так - я не заинтересован его менять, потому что это будет иметь последствия и притом большие. у меня не работает `replace(1,"number");` например

Answer (score 0):

С помощью цепных вызовов можно уместить все в одну строку.

```js
var number = 3,
  html,
  reAmount = /\d{1,5}[.]\d{1,5}/i,
  reNumber = /\d+/;
html = $(".quantity").html();
html = html.replace(reAmount, (parseFloat(html.match(reAmount)) * number)).replace(reNumber, number);

$(".quantity").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">57.100&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
```